MySQL - how to update only some characters in a column value - longtext (DC2Type:array)
MySQL: 8.0.35 - Source distribution
I have longtext (DC2Type:array) column and incorrect some characters values in a column string, so i want to replace this data format:
a:2:{s:7:"content";s:6:"text 1";s:3:"url";s:19:"https://someurl.com";}

to this data format:
a:2:{i:0;s:6:"text 1";i:1;s:19:"https://someurl.com";}

so replace:
s:7:"content"
to:
i:0
and replace:
s:3:"url"
to:
i:1
how to do it ?
regards

Please create a fiddle with sample data

Have you tried the replace function?

Use nested REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)

thank you, replace work correctly !

@Ergest Basha and @Akina
resolved this ticket: sql replace function
thank you
